# Achieving multithreading in PHP

Tags: php

I am writing a kind of test system in php that would test my database records. I have separated php files for every test case. One (master) file is given the test number and the input parameters for that test in the form of URL string. That file determines the test number and calls the appropriate test case based on test number. Now I have a bunch of URL strings to be passed, I want those to be passsed to that (master) file and every test case starts working independently after receiving its parameters.

Comment: If you're asking about multi-threading in PHP, chances are you're either overcomplicating things, or you're using the wrong language. If you're not concerned about blocking, just use `file_get_contents( $url );`

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a single threaded entity, no multithreading currently exists for it. However, there are a few things you can do to achieve similar (but not identical) results for use cases I have come across when people normally ask me about multithreading. Again, there is no multithreading in PHP, but some of the below may help you further in creating something with characteristics that may match your requirement.

- libevent: you could use this to create an event loop for PHP which would make blocking less of an issue.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.libevent.php
- curl_multi: Another useful library that can fire off get/post to other services.
- Process Control: Not used this myself, but may be of value if process control is one aspect of your issue. http://uk.php.net/pcntl
- Gearman: Now this I've used and it's pretty good. It allows you to create workers and spin off processes into a queue. You may also want to look at rabbit-php or ZeroMQ.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not multithreaded, it's singlethreaded. You cannot start new threads within PHP. Your best bet would be a `file_get_contents` (or cURL) to another PHP script to "mimic" threads. True multithreading isn't available in PHP.

You could also have a look at John's post at http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/?q=node/view/254.

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to send the requests back to the server. The request will be handled and the results will be returned.

An example would be:

```
$c = curl_init("http://servername/".$script_name.$params);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
```

Although this is not considered multithreading, it can be used to achieve your goal.

Comment: But this is BLOCKING - hence no mutiple threads. OTOH, the curl_mutli_ functions, although still blocking, can invoke multiple requests concrrently.

Comment: Ah, yes. I wasn't sure about it being multithreading, but it should serve the purpose of the OP.